# with `*args`, keyword arguments become positional?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, arguments, keyword

Example, say I define a function

```
def myfunc(a=1, *args):
    print(a)
    # *args have some other functionality, for example passed to a class instance, or whatever
```

Problem is: when calling `myfunc`, I can't pass the expected positional arguments for `*args` first, then pass keyword argument `a`. For example, if the expected `*args` contain just a number, I can't do

```
myfunc(3, a=4)
```

This would raise an error, stating multiple assignments received for a. I can't do `myfunc(a=4, b=5, 3)` obviously. I can only do

```
myfunc(4, 3)
```

So now it seems, with the `*args`, the keyword argument `a` really becomes positional?

The example here is a function, but it also applies to classes. Say a subclass with `__init__(a=3, *args)` wants some keyword argument `a` and some other 99 required arguments to pass to super. I wouldn't want to repeat the 99 arguments definition in the subclass, but rather do `*args` and pass that to super. But now the keyword argument `a` becomes positional.

This class and subclass example is my real problem in my coding. I want a subclass with an optional, keyword argument `a`, and then 99 required arguments for its super. I don't see a good, clean way around this problem.

I can't be the first to bump into this, but I couldn't find any answer.

Comment: I think the way to do it is get rid of your `a` and use `*kwargs` instead. Then if you still want a default value for `a`, you would have to implement that within your function/class.

As a precision, telling python `*args` is kind of saying "any other arguments that would come". So in your example that raises an error, Python maps the first argument to the named argument it knows about (`a`), and so when you want to explicitly set a value for `a` Python gets confused as it already has a value for it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You meant `**kwargs`? Yeah I understand the reason why this happens, I am just surprised that with `*args` the keyword arguments becomes positional. What I am really running into in my actual coding is more like the class and subclass example, and I don't see a good way around it.

Comment: @Alex. I might be missing something here - but why not just define the function with the keyword argument *after* the `*args`?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7? Maybe in Python 3 one can do that?

Comment: @Alex. Yet another good reason for switching to Python 3 :P

Comment: @ekhumoro The same "problem" applies to Python 3. By putting `a` after `*args` (python 3 only) you make it "keyword-only", that could be a solution but maybe not.

Comment: @MSeifert. It seems a very small price to pay, given that it actually works (unlike the OPs current solution).

Comment: @ekhumoro It's also easy to make it work correctly without requiring Python 3 and making it keyword-only. At least the approach in my answer seems to work for both Python versions and accepts it as positional and keyword argument.

Comment: @MSeifert. That's not the point. The OPs example would fail in exactly the same way in Python 3. So I was simply saying that, *in Python 3*, a keyword-only argument seems a small price to pay to fix that.

Comment: @ekhumoro That's correct. However if I interpret the question correctly it will be just a "workaround" not a "solution".

Comment: @MSeifert. Well, the point is moot, given that the OP is using Python 2 (and in case you didn't notice, I wasn't being entirely serious when I suggested switching to Python 3). Anyway, your answer is clearly correct for Python 2. (PS: I have now upvoted. I forgot to do that earlier - sorry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` isn't positional-only:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def myfunc(a=1, *args):
...     print(a)
>>> inspect.signature(myfunc).parameters['a'].kind
<_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>
```

And indeed it can be passed in as keyword-argument:

```
>>> myfunc(a=4)
4
```

However, as you noted, as soon as you want to provide subsequent positional arguments, you have to provide it as positional parameter. But that has nothing to do with `*args`, that's just how positional arguments work:

```
>>> def myfunc2(a, b):
...     print(a)
>>> myfunc2(1, a=2)
TypeError: myfunc2() got multiple values for argument 'a'
```

It either has to be the first of all positional arguments **or** all arguments have to be passed by name.

However `*args` complicates the situation somewhat, because it only collects positional arguments. That means that if it should collect *anything* you also have to pass in all previous parameters by position.

But in case you want to roll your own special case you could accept just `*args, **kwargs` and first check if it's passed as keyword (named) argument or, if not, as first positional argument:

```
>>> def myfunc3(*args, **kwargs):
...     if 'a' in kwargs:
...         a = kwargs.pop('a')
...     else:
...         a = args[0]
...         args = args[1:]
...     print(a, args, kwargs)
>>> myfunc3(1, a=2)
2 (1,) {}
>>> myfunc3(2, 1)
2 (1,) {}
```

That should give you the results you expected but you need to be explicit in the documentation how the argument should be passed in because it somewhat breaks the semantics of Pythons signature model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution does work, however, as you noted, it's kinda noisy for the code. I am quite SURPRISED at this point. I would imagine what I wanted would be quite common in python programming: You have a base class, then create a subclass that accepts some optional keyword arguments, and bypass other args to super. But apparently, there's no clean way to do it, at least in Python 2.7.

Comment: @Alex Yes, it's a common use-case but the presence of `*args` and/or `**kwargs` always destroys the signature (e.g. [`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) or [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature)). So in Python it's usual to just "copy the parameters" and add the ones you want to add or remove the ones you don't need. Because that preserves introspection and doesn't require "hacks" like the one I mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3 introduced keyword-only arguments: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/

So you can do:

```
def myfunc(*args, a=1):
    print(a)
```

And then `myfunc(3, a=4)` would work fine.